# Unregister view-Viewmodel Prism xamarin dryioc

Tags: prism, dryioc

I have a situation where I need to Unregister a ViewModel and rerregister it .

The reason is that at times I want to inject a "fakeservice" rather than the "real one".

So if I press the "offline" button I need to unregister the viewModels and re-register them so that the Fakeservices are used.

How can i unregister a view-viewmodel using prism and dryioc

I usuall Register like this:

```
  protected override void RegisterTypes(Prism.Ioc.IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MyPage,MyPageViewModel>();
}
```

How do I unregister the above?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you register your View and ViewModel with that extension, it is worth noting that the ViewModel itself is not registered with the container, it is only registered with the ViewModelLocationProvider which provides the ViewModel type to resolve for a given View.

It is also worth noting here that ViewModels are resolved with a Transient Lifetime which means that each time it is resolved you get a new instance, so all you would really need to do is Navigate away and then back again.

Comment: @Haukinger mm not sure about your suggestion but I will try it.

Comment: that is very interesting. 
As soon as the applaunches my viewModel will be registered and soon after 
a call is made instantiating that viewmodel with the "Real service" 
Now for some reason in dev mode I want to go offline by pressing a button and now i need to inject/use the fakeservice
Could you expand a bit more of what I would have todo when I want to use the "fakeservice".
I have unregistered  container.unregister<IMyService,MyRealService>();
I have register my fakeservice "container.Register<IMyService,MyFakeService>" 
Not sure how i can implement what you suggest.Thanks

Comment: are you saying i should simply re register the viewmodel when I want to switch to a "fake service" implementation that is injected in the viewmodel? thanks for your time in replying

Comment: no... I'm saying that the ViewModel it self is never actually registered... When you navigate the container simply provides it because it is a concrete type... When you use the `RegisterForNavigation<TView,TViewModel>` Prism is merely mapping which ViewModel goes with the View to avoid a more costly reflection lookup.

Answer (score 0):

> The reason is that at times I want to inject a "fakeservice" rather than the "real one".

No need to unregister the view model. The service is injected when the instance is created.

But you should not use the container for this anyway - create a service provider instead, then you can switch that one to the currently active service. That's even possible transparently for the consumer if the service provider implements the service interface itself.

```
public interface IService
{
    void DoStuff();
}

public interface IServiceProvider
{
    void SetActiveService( Type serviceType );
}

internal ServiceProvider : IServiceProvider, IService
{
    void IService.DoStuff() => _currentService.DoStuff();

    public void SetActiveService( Type serviceType )
    {
        _currentService = _container.Resolve( serviceType );
    }

    private IService _currentService;
}
```

Add some synchronization and error handling and refactor away the container reference for production, though.

With Unity I'd register the provider as unnamed standard implementation and register all actual services as named implementations and have an `IEnumerable<Func<IService>>` injected into the service provider. Perhaps DryIoc offers similar functionality.

Comment: This is terrible advice, you should not be suggesting that someone follow an anti-pattern.

Comment: Can you  elaborate? The suggested `IServiceProvider` is no service locator but rather an application state that can be switched between multiple behaviours. As noted, passing the type is for illustrational purpose only. In production, one should find something else to differentiate application states (constant names, for example). I'd rather say that using the container to manage application state would be an anti-pattern.